# Why doesn't my text float on top of my image?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am making a homepage and when I add an image in, my navigation goes under it, I would like to know why it doesn't stay on top.

[image]

This is the html Code.

```
<img id="img" src="Img/navigation.png">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <a href="index.html"><li>Homepage</li></a>
                <li>Forum</li>
                <li>Donate</li>
                <li>Vote</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

This is the CSS

```
nav {
    width: auto;
    float:right;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    display:inline-block;
}

nav ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:10px 8px;
}

nav li{
    list-style:none;
    padding:15px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: green;
}

nav a,nav a:visited{
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:20px;
}
```

Why doesn't the text float on top?

Comment: You mean to say stay as a background of your navigation bar ? You should keep the image as a background in order to achieve what you are doing.

Comment: For that you would have to use the image as a background.

Comment: @vitro where would i set it as a background image. I will be having multiple Images o this page. Including a different background image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use image as a background: http://jsfiddle.net/nH6GK/

```
nav {
    width: auto;
    float:right;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    display:inline-block;

    background: url('http://placehold.it/500x150') no-repeat center;
}
```

Comment: or change the structure, wrap `nav` in a `div` and use the image as a background to that `div`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

HTML

```
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <a href="index.html"><li>Homepage</li></a>
                <li>Forum</li>
                <li>Donate</li>
                <li>Vote</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
<img id="img" src="Img/navigation.png">
```

CSS:

```
nav {
    width: auto;
    float:right;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    display:inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top:0;
}

img {

position: absolute;
top:0;
z-index: 1;
```

}

Or just put the image as a background. But since you are asking here, I guess you want something more specific.